# PHP Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in

Tags: typo3, php-7.2

PHP Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /opt/lampp/htdocs/deingreidcht/typo3conf/ext/toctoc_comments/pi1/class.toctoc_comments_pi1.php
how to solve this

Here is my code, I have applied condition,

```
if (count($rowsrf)== 0) {
```

Comment: Provide more information about what `$rowsrf` is. Currently its unsolvable. All I can say is that `$rowsrf` is neither an array nor an object which implements `Countable`..... Also please use `\count` instead of `count` and `===` instead ob `==`. `count` will return an integer!

Comment: `$rowsrf` could be an object () and you can't count this as you have mentioned. You have to parse this to the standard array. Hope this makes sense. Your code should be `if (count((array)$rowsrf)== 0) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can typo3 standard method 
For example in your controller

```
$this->yourextRepository->findAll()->count();
```

May this will help you!